# How to add a link in ui form component note?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

Is there a way to add note with link to form ui component. I have try the below code but it doesn't work

```
<field name="customer_id">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Model\Config\Source\Customer</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer_id</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_id</item>
        <item name="notice" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<a href="customer/index/new" target="_blank">Create New Customer</a>]]></item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field>
```

Also I checked the tooltip. But the new customer link doesn't work(It works with ext).

```
<field name="customer_id">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Model\Config\Source\Customer</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer_id</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_id</item>
        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string" translate="true">customer/index/new</item>
            <item name="description" xsi:type="string">Create New Customer</item>
        </item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<field name="customer_id">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Model\Config\Source\Customer</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer_id</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_id</item>
        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}customer/index/new</item>
            <item name="description" xsi:type="string">Create New Customer</item>
        </item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field>
```

You have pass full url as link in your xml file and check.

```
<item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}customer/index/new</item>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Iam creating an extension. So can't set  full url as link.

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: It is not working. It just reload the current page.

Comment: have you created customer/index/new action, first have you checked its working or not

Comment: just set {{baseUrl}}customer/index/new

Comment: I think issue in your controller action customer/index/new, please share new controller action code?

Comment: I just want to redirect the link to default new customer page (admin side).

Comment: Please check this screenshot
http://i.prntscr.com/26a4a43735574f419e151d014023d869.png

Comment: Please last try,             <item name="link" xsi:type="string" translate="true">/customer/index/new</item> in your code please add prefix slash(/) remove var and check

Comment: Now it is Not found. 
http://i.prntscr.com/edda595917384493b3fbe151b9f5f41f.png

Comment: ok no prob, just replace your item name link with  with <item name="url" xsi:type="string">customer/index/new</item>

Comment: No,it is not working.Now it is not clickable. Tooltip supports link only

Comment: when you use link as item name at that time you have to pass full url in your xml file.